# Find element without class or id within element - jQuery

Tags: jquery, element

```
<td class="box">
<span>
<img src='http://something.com' />
</span>
</td>
```

How would you select the span tag?
I need to add an extra image with jQuery (for a user script), but selecting the span and then adding an element is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any of these should work

```
$('span', '.box');
$('.box span');
$('.box > span');
$('.box').find('span');
$('.box').children('span');
$('.box').children('span').first();
```

etc. ....

or even

```
$('img[src$="something.com"]').before('<img src="newimage.jpg" />');
$('span:has(img)');
$('span').filter(function() { return $(this).find('img[src$="something.com"]').length })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that, but apparently I did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img[src="http://something.com"]').closest('span');
```

If you want to target only the specific `span` that holds image with a particular `src` then , you can use the above selector.

But if you want to target All the `td.box` with span's as their descendent then the suggestion by **@adeneo** should work.

Comment: I think he needs to find the `span` in order to *add* the image, from the way I read the question.

Comment: @beauXjames.. can u please explain ??

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.box').find('span');
```

will do the trick!

Comment: $('.box') :: add the '.' to qualify class

Answer (score 1):

$('.box span') would let you select the span

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery find method http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

With just the snippet you've shown, I'd probably use something like this:

```
$('td.box span')
```

If there are other parents to the td.box you could use those to get more specific.